# Diodes-practical analysis

Tags: diodes, parallel, series, homework, reverse-bias

Need to find VR1 and VR2 in the circuit when: A) D1: forward D2: forward B) D1: reverse D2: forward C) D1: forward D2: reverse D) D1: reverse D2: reverse. Show calculations. E=9v R1=10kohms R2= 4.7kohms[image]

[image]
I calculated 8.3v for VR1 but I don't know how to calculate VR2. The right side of the chart shows what I got from the meter when I built the circuit.

Comment: Write a KVL equation for the outer loop (E, VD1, VR1, and VD2) for your first case.  This will show you the missing piece for case 1.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the accuracy needed, you can assume the forward voltage drop across a diode is 0.7 V and in reverse bias it is an open circuit.

Increased accuracy would require iterating with the [diode equation](https://www.pveducation.org/pvcdrom/pn-junctions/diode-equation) for a more exact solution.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113673/discussion-on-answer-by-relayman357-diodes-practical-analysis).

Comment: @VoltageSpike Thanks. Appropriate.